# Using Code Nuggets as property values

Tags: asp.net

I have the following code

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" runat="server">

<asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1" Text="<%= MyHelperClass.Value%>"></asp:Label>    
<%= MyHelperClass.Value%>

</asp:Content>
```

The Label doesn't work, it has the Text `<%= MyHelperClass.Value%>` the next row returns the expected value.

Question: can i use those code nuggets to set values of the property of an control?

Comment: `MyHelperClass.Value` is a property of a static class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why it's working outside and not with Control?

Well `<%= %>` is called `Content Code Nuggets` because they inject content in the html which is sent by server to browser. It does the work of `Reponse.Write`. We use this mainly to call any code written in code behind file for example, you have a simple method in your code behind:-

```
public string UserCity()
{
   return "London";
}
```

Then you can call it from aspx page like this:-

```
You live in <%= UserCity() %>.
```

Content code nuggets used to inject the html to response at the last in `PreRender` event and thus it's called late binding. This is the main reason why it is NOT working with your control.

> How to fix this?

You can use the data binding code nuggets (`<%# %>`). These are used with `DataBound` controls but you can force the Page's DataBound or control's DataBound method to bind your control like this:-

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1" Text="<%# MyHelperClass.Value%>"></asp:Label>
```

Call `DataBind` method in code behind:-

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Page.DataBind();
    }
}
```