# From C# to ASPX wrong encoding

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a favicon that I have to pass from server side. I did it like this:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/ico" href="<%= favIcon%>" />
```

On the server side I have added a public string named `favIcon` and then

```
favIcon = "Generic_Icon_2015.ico";
```

If I look at the Web Debugger page on chrome i see the result like this

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/ico" href="&lt;% = favIcon%>" />
```

so he wasn't able to recognize the `<` symbol. I also get

```
http://localhost/AL07/%3C%%20=%20favIcon%%3E 400 (Bad Request)
```

I noticed that if I remove `runat="server"` from `<head>` then it works fine..

What's happening?

Comment: try assigning  `favIcon` a relative or full url

Comment: I am not sure if this will totally answer your question, but check out this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11510502/understanding-the-runat-server-attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Data Bind Code nuggets instead:-

```
 href="<%# favIcon%>"
```

But, you need to call `Page.DataBind()` method on page load like this:-

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!IsPostBack)
   {
      Page.DataBind();
   }
}
```

For reason why your code (Content code nuggets) is not working, [Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33125406/1529657).