# How to write property direct to Label Text property in HTML

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm trying to write my codebehind property FirstName to Text property of Label. But I don't want to do it from code behind. This is my example:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# "Hello " + this.FirstName %>'></asp:Label>
```

But it doesn't show anything. How can I correct it?

Comment: Try to replace # with =: `Text='<%= "Hello " + this.FirstName %>'`

Comment: @Phate01- That won't work with a control.

Comment: It doesn't work. This solution return mi this: <%= "Hello" %>

Comment: @Earlgray - So were you able to achieve this without code behind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why you are trying to do that, but you can do it by calling the `DataBind` method of control like this:-

```
public string FirstName { get; set; }
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FirstName = "XYZ";
    if (!IsPostBack)
          Label1.DataBind();
}
```

**Update:**

Data Bind code nuggets `<%#` will work only with DataBound Controls. To make them work with normal ASP.NET controls, you will have to explicitly call the `DataBind` method of that control like I did above.

```
Text='<%# "Hello " + this.FirstName %>'
```

Will print `Hello XYZ` here. You can also check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33125406/1529657) for further explanation.

Comment: He don't want to use codebehind. Also, if you would use it it would be simply `Label1.Text = "Hallo " + this.FirstName;`

Comment: @TimSchmelter - Yeah agree, OP doesn't want to use code behind but for this to work (code nugget) `DataBind` method has to be invoked. And it will work I guess you tried it with `<%=` try it with data bind code nugget `<%#` and it will work just fine.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - That's what I mentioned in the update, you can't use the property directly with code nuggets like this - `<%=` it will not work.